# T-SQL: How do I create a unique key that is case sensitive?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, constraints

How do I create a unique constraint on a `varchar` field that is case sensitive (SQL Server 2005)?

Currently my constraint looks like this:

```
alter table MyTable
add constraint UK_MyTable_MyUniqueKey unique nonclustered (MyCol)
```

When I try to insert the following two values, I get a "Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint..." error.

```
insert into MyTable (MyCol) values ('ABC')
insert into MyTable (MyCol) values ('abc') --causes a violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UK_MyTable_MyUnqiueKey'
```

I would like the two differently-cased values to be handled as unqiue. I imagine it will involve the following code, but I do not know how it changes my `add constraint` syntax.

```
COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
```

Comment: do you mean case 'sensitive' or insensitive? if ABC and abc both are resolved the same then that is a case 'in'sensitive comparison. You might restate the question

Comment: So, what collation caused "abc" and "ABC" to collide? UTF-8? Do you remember? Thanks.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

This will change the column to be case sensitive.  I don't think there's any change to your constraint...

```
ALTER TABLE mytable 
ALTER COLUMN mycolumn VARCHAR(10) 
COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
```

Any selects or joins on this column will become case sensitive as a result of this operation.

Comment: Will this cause all selects on that column to be case-sensitive as well?

Comment: Everything involved with this column will be case sensitive.

Comment: You'll have to drop the constraint, run the ALTER, add the PK again to deal with the dependency

Comment: How do I do this if the column consists not only of Latin1 characters, but also those of other alphabets, coded in UTF-8 (as is standard in most applications nowadays)?

Answer (score 4):

You can only set the case-sensitivity of the data in the database (smallest granularity of column). You can't set case-sensitivity of an index - that would be equivalent to being able to index on an expression, which is possible in some databases but not Sql Server.