# Entity Framework Core 7 code-first: related entity/navigation property not being loaded even when included

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0

Using Entity Framework Core 7 code-first, I have two entities as follows:

User

```
public string UserId { get; set; }

[ForeignKey(nameof(UserId))]
public Queue Queue { get; set; }
```

Queue

```
public string QueueId { get; set; }
```

Each `User` always has one `Queue`, and the `UserId` (which is the primary key of `User`) also happens to be a foreign key to `Queue`.

Each `Queue` has 0..1 `Users`. I know it sounds strange, but think of `UserId/QueueId` as an email address that may be for a single user or a group. If it's a group, it doesn't tie back to a user, as the members of that group are worked out elsewhere. Hence the lack of a complimentary `User` property on the `Queue` entity.

Anyway, I would like to be able to access a user's queue via the nav property, so I added it along with the `ForeignKey` attribute shown above to tell it to use the `UserId`. The migration generated the following code, which looks correct as far as I can tell:

```
migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
    name: "FK_Users_Queues_UserId",
    table: "Users",
    column: "UserId",
    principalTable: "Queues",
    principalColumn: "QueueId",
    onDelete: ReferentialAction.NoAction);

...and from snapshot:

modelBuilder.Entity("Entities.User", b =>
{
    b.HasOne("Entities.Queue", "Queue")
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey("UserId")
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
        .IsRequired();

    b.Navigation("Queue");
});
```

But when I try to query a `User` and have it load the `Queue` property, for some reason it doesn't load it - `Queue` remains null even though there's a record in the table that matches.

```
var user = _context.Users
                   .Include(x => x.Queue)
                   .FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == userId);
```

Couple strange things I've noticed:

1. If I add `AsNoTracking()`, it magically starts working:

```
var user = _context.Users
                   .Include(x => x.Queue)
                   .AsNoTracking()
                   .FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == userId);
```

2. Oddly enough, I have other one-to-*many* collections on the `User` entity, and they all behave as expected. If I `.Include` any of them, they are loaded and available upon query. For some reason this one-to-one is an oddball.
3. If I use projection, the `Queue` property is accessible regardless of whether I use an explicit `.Include` (which seems like it ties back to the lack of tracking since projections don't track):

```
var us = _context.Users
                 .Where(x => x.UserId == userId)
                 .Select(x => new { QueueId = x.Queue.QueueId });
```

I am using the default with EF Core 7, which I believe is lazy loading, and I don't have any desire to change that.

I'm just trying to understand the behavior. Is this expected? If so, what is the proper way of handling this?

**UPDATE:**

Apparently this has to do with how EF determines matches involving case-sensitivity around varchar keys.  I had completely been glossing over the fact that my User.UserId and Queue.QueueId were only matches **if the case-sensitivity of the database was being honored**(SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS/case insensitive).  I guess because EF was able to match when *not* tracking, I never even considered it.

I still don't understand why the database collation isn't honored, but I certainly don't understand why tracking/notracking would make it change that behavior.  I plan to open a bug on github later today, but they can provide some feedback.

To be clear, ultimately, I updated the Queue.QueueId value to be an *exact* match to the User.UserId and everything started working as expected.

**UPDATE-2:**

See the accepted answer I posted with a valid workaround involving the use of a custom value comparer.

Thank you!

Comment: For #3: This is how projection works. You don't need an explicit include. Also, see this , please - https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/256

Comment: Do you perhaps initialize the `Queue` property in `User`'s constructor or by a property initializer?

Comment: `[ForeignKey(nameof(UserId))]` on `User.Queue` looks a bit strange to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a usable workaround involving the use of a custom value comparer to force comparison to be case insensitive.

Reference [link](https://github.com/dotnet/EntityFramework.Docs/issues/2979#issuecomment-753344003)

Relevant code:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    var comparer = new ValueComparer<string>(
        (l, r) => string.Equals(l, r, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase),
        v => v.ToUpper().GetHashCode(),
        v => v);
    
    modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>().Property(e => e.Id).Metadata.SetValueComparer(comparer);
    
    modelBuilder.Entity<Post>(b =>
    {
        b.Property(e => e.Id).Metadata.SetValueComparer(comparer);
        b.Property(e => e.BlogId).Metadata.SetValueComparer(comparer);
    });
}
```

Another relevant stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32224102/entity-framework-varchar-foreign-key-case-insensitive) for reference.