# How to do a case sensitive search in WHERE clause (I'm using SQL Server)?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to do a case sensitive search in my SQL query. But by default, SQL Server does not consider the case of the strings.

Any idea on how to do a case sensitive search in SQL query?

Answer (score 264, accepted):

Can be done via [changing the Collation](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/case_sensitive_search_in_sql_server.htm). By default it is case insensitive.

Excerpt from the link:

```
SELECT 1
FROM dbo.Customers
WHERE   CustID = @CustID COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
AND     OrderID = @OrderID COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
```

Or, [change the columns to be case sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485359/t-sql-how-do-i-create-a-unique-key-that-is-case-sensitive/485394#485394).

You can also apply COLLATE to LIKE to make it case sensitive - e.g.,

```
SELECT    *
FROM     tbl_Partners
WHERE    PartnerName COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS LIKE 'MyEx%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
```

Comment: How to use when we have in instead =. like WHERE   CustID in (@CustID)

Comment: Collation works for most cases, but if you've got other language characters in your data, it will return false positives: `/schwarz-weiß` versus: `/schwarz-weiss`

Comment: applies to LIKE clause ?

Answer (score 178):

By using collation or casting to binary, like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Users
WHERE   
    Username = @Username COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
    AND Password = @Password COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
    AND Username = @Username 
    AND Password = @Password
```

The duplication of username/password exists to give the engine the possibility of using indexes. The collation above is a Case Sensitive collation, change to the one you need if necessary.

The second, casting to binary, could be done like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Users
WHERE   
    CAST(Username as varbinary(100)) = CAST(@Username as varbinary))
    AND CAST(Password as varbinary(100)) = CAST(@Password as varbinary(100))
    AND Username = @Username 
    AND Password = @Password
```

Comment: People reading this question may also find it useful to read how to change the column itself to be case sensitive which eliminates the need for using collation in the WHERE clause. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/485394/908677

Comment: The cast as varbinary method worked for me when used directly on the database, but did not work when sending the same statement from a .NET application -- no idea why. But the collate method worked fine.

Comment: This answer would be perfect if it included an explanation of where to put the term searched for, i.e. where the phrase similar to a regular `like "*word or phrase*"` SQL search would be inserted.

Comment: @CannedMan - You can use the above collate solution the same way with the LIKE statement. Simply do the following to return all upper case 'D's. "SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE ColumnName like '%D%'  COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS"

Comment: It doesn't work with czech alphabet. Tested word: 'ukázka'. It is in the table as a singe word in a column, but your search didn't find it.

Comment: Still an issue at: Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8   May 12 2022 23:11:24

Answer (score 15):

You can make the query using convert to varbinary – it’s very easy.
Example:

```
Select * from your_table where convert(varbinary, your_column) = convert(varbinary, 'aBcD')
```

Comment: It doesn't work with czech alphabet. Tested word: 'ukázka'. It is in the table as a singe word in a column, but your search didn't find it.

Answer (score 7):

**USE BINARY_CHECKSUM**

```
SELECT 
FROM Users
WHERE   
    BINARY_CHECKSUM(Username) = BINARY_CHECKSUM(@Username)
    AND BINARY_CHECKSUM(Password) = BINARY_CHECKSUM(@Password)
```

Comment: Wouldn't this mean, that it's no longer an exact comparison? There might be sometimes that it returns true that they aren't actually the same?

Comment: I agree @O'Rooney this will on occasion return false positives.

Answer (score 7):

In MySQL if You don't want to change the collation and want to perform case sensitive search then just use **binary** keyword like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE binary username=@search_parameter and binary password=@search_parameter
```

Comment: That's not a valid SQL Server query. I think that's MySQL

Comment: Works perfectly on MySQL

Comment: this works for me in mysql! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

use HASHBYTES

```
declare @first_value nvarchar(1) = 'a'
declare @second_value navarchar(1) = 'A'

if HASHBYTES('SHA1',@first_value) = HASHBYTES('SHA1',@second_value) begin
    print 'equal'
end else begin
    print 'not equal'
end

-- output:
-- not equal
```

...in where clause

```
declare @example table (ValueA nvarchar(1), ValueB nvarchar(1))

insert into @example (ValueA, ValueB)
values  ('a', 'A'),
        ('a', 'a'),
        ('a', 'b')

select  ValueA + ' = ' + ValueB
from    @example
where   hashbytes('SHA1', ValueA) = hashbytes('SHA1', ValueB)

-- output:
-- a = a

select  ValueA + ' <> ' + ValueB
from    @example
where   hashbytes('SHA1', ValueA) <> hashbytes('SHA1', ValueB)

-- output:
-- a <> A
-- a <> b
```

or to find a value

```
declare @value_b nvarchar(1) = 'A'

select  ValueB + ' = ' + @value_b
from    @example
where   hashbytes('SHA1', ValueB) = hasbytes('SHA1', @value_b)

-- output:
-- A = A
```

Answer (score 5):

use  Latin1_General_CS as your collation in your sql db

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from incidentsnew1 
where BINARY_CHECKSUM(CloseBy) = BINARY_CHECKSUM(Upper(CloseBy))
```

Answer (score 2):

use below query to get result with case sensitive.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE BINARY COLUMN_NAME='YOUR_FILTER'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do by simply altering column collation as

```
Alter Table UserMaster 
Alter Column Password varchar(50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in Entity Framework approarch:

```
var customers = context.Customers
.Where(c => EF.Functions.Collate(c.Name, "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS") == "John")
.ToList();
```

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/collations-and-case-sensitivity#explicit-collation-in-a-query

Answer (score -6):

Just as others said, you can perform a case sensitive search. Or just change the collation format of a specified column as me. For the User/Password columns in my database I change them to collation through the following command:

```
ALTER TABLE `UserAuthentication` CHANGE `Password` `Password` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_cs NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Do NOT store passwords as plaintext!  They should've been hashed and salted, and then the comparison is on the hash and salt!  This is simply a terrible answer!