# Case insensitive search in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a database with `Arabic_BIN` collation on Microsoft SQL Server 2005.

If I run this query:

```
SELECT ID FROM maj_Users WHERE UserName = 'mahdi'
```

I'll get nothing, but if I run this query:

```
SELECT ID FROM maj_Users WHERE UserName = 'Mahdi'
```

I'll get a cell... Seems that SQL Server is searching database case-sensitively, but I want to search database case-insensitively.

Is there any way?

EDIT: Also I have tried `SELECT ID FROM maj_Users WHERE UserName LIKE 'mahdi'` but it didn't work...

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831105/how-to-do-a-case-sensitive-search-in-where-clause-im-using-sql-server

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can override a COLLATION defined on database or column level in a comparison using the COLLATE keyword:

```
SELECT ID FROM maj_Users WHERE UserName = 'Mahdi' COLLATE [collation name]
```

To find collations for case-insensitive Arabic, use the query

```
select * from fn_helpcollations()
where name like 'Arabic%' and name like '%CI%'
```

Arabic_CI_AI or Arabic_100_CI_AI seems to be the right choice for you.

Comment: Thanks. in finding collations query, it will return nothing. `arabic` should be replaced with `Arabic`.

Answer (score 8):

SQL Server is not searching the database in a case sensitive manner, nor it does it on a case insensitive one. It does it according to the [**collation**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144260%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) of the column involved. There are case sensitive and case insensitive collation. I recommend you read [Collation and Unicode Support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143503(v=sql.105)). Do **not** start doing `UPPER` or `LOWER` comparisons, that is not the right approach and it has serious performance implications due to sarg-ability.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion about not doing `UPPER` and `LOWER` comparisons.