# How to search case sensitive string in MS Sql server?

Tags: sql-server

how to search case sensitive data like **user_name** and **password** in ms SQL server.
In MySQl It is done by **BINARY()** function.

Comment: You keep raw passwords in the database?

Comment: Nice guide here: http://www.abstraction.net/ViewArticle.aspx?articleID=72

Comment: same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831105/how-to-do-a-case-sensitive-search-in-where-clause-im-using-sql-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create column with case sensitive collate, and try this:

**Query:**

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
      Name VARCHAR(50) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
)

INSERT INTO @temp (Name)
VALUES 
    ('Ankit Kumar'),
    ('DevArt'),
    ('Devart')

SELECT * 
FROM @temp
WHERE Name LIKE '%Art'
```

**Output:**

```
DevArt
```

***Or try this similar code -***

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (Name NVARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @temp (Name)
VALUES 
    ('Ankit Kumar'),
    ('DevArt'),
    ('Devart')

SELECT * 
FROM @temp
WHERE Name LIKE '%Art' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
```

Answer (score 1):

Can do this using Casting to Binary

```
SELECT * FROM UsersTable
WHERE   
    CAST(Username as varbinary(50)) = CAST(@Username as varbinary(50))
    AND CAST(Password as varbinary(50)) = CAST(@Password as varbinary(50))
    AND Username = @Username 
    AND Password = @Password
```

Comment: Good answer, but use CAST reduces performance and, in some cases, the server will not be able to use indexes on these columns.

Comment: @Devart: Yes, Your answer is actual solution of this question. but i just posted this answer as another approach/solution.

Comment: I didn't want to criticize your answer :). I just wanted to inform you about possible problems when used this method.

Comment: Thank u so much Pankaj and  Devart for your quick and accurate solution.It solved my problem.