# Querying a database for username and password

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlcommand

I'm totally new to C#. I am validating username and password with case-sensitive 
from database sql server 2008. Here is my login code; what should I do?

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=db_WiBo;Integrated Security=True");

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from tb_Account where Username= '"+textBox1.Text+"'  AND Password= '"+textBox2.Text+"' ", conn);

conn.Open();
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

if (reader.HasRows)
{
   reader.Close();
   this.Hide();
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your `SqlCommand` has a [SQL Injection vulnerability](http://www.troyhunt.com/2013/07/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-sql.html). You appear to be storing your passwords in plain-text too, not good.

Comment: The first thing you should do is remove that big SQL injection risk by using parametrized queries. The second thing would probably be checking the collation on your database field/table to enable case sensitivity... and the third would be to hash passwords in your database.

Comment: +Hash passwords, don't store them... and use a good hash function: http://throwingfire.com/storing-passwords-securely/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) you should be using stored procedures or parameterised query instead of SQL Concatenation. you are presenting a huge SQL Server injection security flaw in your code already.

what is the problem you are having? code looks fine - are you sure the inputs match the data in the database if there are no records being retrieved?

the code simply executes the query and if found, closes the reader and hides the form.

you should also not store raw passwords in the DB - another security flaw. instead, hash them/encrypt them and check that value against the hashed/encrypted value from the input.
for case sensitivity, you could use Collation

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391.aspx

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/30/case-sensitive-sql-query-search/

Answer (score 2):

A few things:

1. You are missing a ';' at the end of `SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()`.
2. As was already mentioned, use a [Stored Procedure](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174792(v=sql.80).aspx) for what you are doing.
3. As was also mentioned, use [parameterized queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738521(v=vs.100).aspx) since you are accepting input from textboxes.
4. Use a [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02(v=vs.110).aspx) to manage your connection and command objects.
5. Don't forget to `.Close()` your connection when you are done.
6. Oh, and I almost forgot, [hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181198/how-to-hash-a-password) your passwords!

Here is an example of the above:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=db_WiBo;Integrated Security=True"))
{
   using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT * from tb_Account where Username= '@username'  AND Password= '@password' ", conn))
   {
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", textBox1.Text);
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", textBox2.Text);
      conn.Open();

      SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
      if (reader.HasRows)
      {
         reader.Close();
         this.Hide();
      }
      conn.Close();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Other than your SQL injection issues, you need to use a collation or cast to binary. I found another SO question that has a bunch of helpful things: 
[How to do a case sensitive search in WHERE clause (I'm using SQL Server)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831105/how-to-do-a-case-sensitive-search-in-where-clause-im-using-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

First of all: Do not use string concat for that. This can easily be used for code injection.

You can use stored procedures instead, or LinQ to SQL or even use the built-in membershipprovider

Answer (score 1):

Notwithstanding the design issues already pointed out with respect to security, if your SQL Server instance's default collation is case-insensitive, you'll need to select a suitable collation. The default collation for a SQL Server installation is [usually, depending on the server locale] `SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1_CI_AS`, meaning Latin-1 code page, case-insensitive, accent-sensitive.

When you create a database, you can specify a default collation for that database. And when you create a table, you may specify the collation to be used for each `char`, `varchar`, `nchar` or `nvarchar` column.

You may also change these via appropriate DDL statements. Note that altering the collatino may affect data integrity, causing things like primary keys and unique indices to be broken.

Create a table with and specifying the collation for its columns is easy:

```
create table account
(
  id       int         not null identity(1,1) primary key clustered ,
  user_id  varchar(32) collate SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1_CS_AS not null unique ,
  password varchar(32) collate SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1_CS_AS not null unique ,
  ...
)
```

You may use `alter table` and `alter database` to change the collations as well.

Supported collations can be found at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180175.aspx and http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188046.aspx

You should

- Note that mixed collations can cause problems when comparing 2 columns, and
- Heed the security issues raised by others.