# Data Input asp.net C# SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio, database-connection

Hey guys I am using a connection string database set-up inside visual studios 2012.
I am trying to send data to the database there are no errors in the code but its not running, any help would be fantastic as i have been at it for a few hours now and need some sleep.
Thanks.

**Default page code**

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection("Data Source = (LocalDB)\v11.0; Initial Catalog = Database1; Integrated Security = true");
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Adopter (FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME) VALUES (@FIRSTNAME,@LASTNAME)", cs);
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@FIRSTNAME", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = firstname.Text;
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@LASTNAME", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = lastname.Text;

            cs.Open();
            da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cs.Close();
        }

        protected void firstname_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void lastname_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


        }
    }
```

**SQL code**

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Adopter] (
    [FIRSTNAME]  VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [LASTNAME]   VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,   
);
```

I know it will be something simple... I just cant see it.

Comment: Is it writing to your table or not?  Are you even able to connect to the database?  "It is not running", is not descriptive enough for us to help you.

Comment: The web app loads allows me to type in to the text boxes, when I click the button it says there is a problem with cs.open. So it's not inputting the data into the database tables.

Comment: You need to specify your 'DataSource' (the database instance) in your connection string along with your 'Initial Catalog' (which is the database name (you have that already)).

Comment: Thank you Brian, so not my PC name but the database instance. I shall try it. Thanks again.

Comment: Of course. No problem at all.

Comment: My two cents: I would test your connection separately following this method mentioned here:
http://www.gotknowhow.com/articles/test-a-database-connection-string-using-notepad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as we discussed in comments, it looks like the issue you have is with your connection string.  You have:

```
SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection("Data Source = (LocalDB)\v11.0; 
Initial Catalog = Database1; Integrated Security = true");
```

What you need is:

```
SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection("Data Source = .\SqlInstanceName; 
Initial Catalog = Database1; Integrated Security = true");
```

The data source is the instance on your local machine, a hosted database or some other flavor of a Sql instance and the 'Initial Catalog' is the actual database name.

PS - I *highly* recommend that you look into the [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02(v=vs.110).aspx) keyword and wrap your command and connection objects with it so that when they fall out-of-scope, they are managed for you.  It looks a bit like this when you use them:

```
using (SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection())
{
   // Some code can go here.

   using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
   {
      // More code can go here.
   }
}
```

I have a more comprehensive answer about it on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19936024/querying-a-database-for-username-and-password/19936424#19936424) post.  Happy coding!