# how to make log in form case sensitive

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have created a simple program with log in form. It works in a very simple way but I observed that when logging in, it is not case sensitive. For example if my username is `Test` and I would log in using `test` it would still be accepted.

```
SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection("Data Source=LAFAYETTE-PC;Initial Catalog=Thesis;Integrated Security=True");
connect.Open();
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM AdminCredentials WHERE Username = '" + LogInUsername.Text + "' AND Password  = '" + LogInPassword.Text + "' ", connect);
SqlDataReader reader;
reader = command.ExecuteReader();
int count = 0;
while (reader.Read())
{
    count += 1;
}

if (count == 1)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Successfully Logged In!");
    MainForm form2 = new MainForm();
    form2.ShowDialog();
}
else if (count > 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Incorrect username and passsword");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Username or password is incorrect");

}
```

any ideas? Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You may consider the following : [How to do a case sensitive search in WHERE clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831105/how-to-do-a-case-sensitive-search-in-where-clause-im-using-sql-server)

Comment: you've got a serious SQL injection problem.

Comment: The injection problem is an issue but the entire way you are handling passwords is problematic. They should be salted and hashed instead of stored in plain text. Not only would this protect the passwords, you would also have the answer to making your passwords case sensitive.

Comment: You shouldn't be worried about case sensitive user names when you're storing clear text passwords and have some delicious delicious sql injection vulnerabilities. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

append " COLLATE Latin1_GENERAL_CS_AS" to your query

```
new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM AdminCredentials WHERE Username = '" + LogInUsername.Text + "' AND Password  = '" + LogInPassword.Text + "'  COLLATE Latin1_GENERAL_CS_AS"
```

and read about Sql Injection...

Comment: lol, I'm really a noob when it comes to that... I'm just trying my best to learn this! Anyway, thanks so much!