# How do I get around case sensitive fields when in SQL

Tags: sql

My code is:

```
CURSOR get_party_description is      
      select party_name  
      from   ifsapp.IDENTITY_PAY_INFO_ALL
      where  party_type    = :NEW.PARTY_TYPE
      and    identity   = identity_
```

`:NEW_PARTY_TYPE = 'SUPPLIER'` while the value in the field is 'Supplier'.  This code will pull back no records but if I change it to 'Supplier', it finds the record

How do I change to search with out matching the case?

Answer (score 2):

You can convert both the variable and the field to upper or lower case.

```
where  UPPER(party_type)    = UPPER(:NEW.PARTY_TYPE)
```

This might cause a table space scan as the index on the field would be Case sensitive.

you can get around this by adding a generated column that is upper case and indexing that.

Comment: thank you!  Not sure why I didn't think of that.  I was over thinking this

Comment: Also consider the use of collation, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831105/how-to-do-a-case-sensitive-search-in-where-clause-im-using-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

Change both of your values to upper case. Example:

```
CURSOR get_party_description is      
      select party_name  
      from   ifsapp.IDENTITY_PAY_INFO_ALL
      where  UPPER(party_type)    = UPPER('SUPPLIER')
      and    identity   = identity_
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides converting both strings to the same case (upper- or lower-) and then comparing them for equality, most SQL dialects allow one to do a case-insensitive comparison by using the `LIKE` operator, as follows:

```
CURSOR get_party_description is      
    select party_name  
    from   ifsapp.IDENTITY_PAY_INFO_ALL
    where  party_type LIKE :NEW.PARTY_TYPE
    and    identity   = identity_
```