# SQL query comparison

Tags: sql

1) `select name from city where countrycode="JPN" ;`

2) `select name from city where countrycode='JPN' ;`

3) `select name from city where countrycode="jPn" ;`

all the above queries are working in query 2 i am using single quotes and in 3 query i am using mixture of upper case and lowercase character . why it is producting correct output??.

Comment: what dbms are you using?

Comment: Obviously both quotation marks are allowed in the syntax of your db server. And wether the comparison is case-sensitive or not depends on the _collation_ configured for your column, table or database.

Comment: SQL queries are typically case insensitive

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do a case sensitive search in WHERE clause (I'm using SQL Server)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831105/how-to-do-a-case-sensitive-search-in-where-clause-im-using-sql-server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess I misread the original question. Some database implementations are case insensitive are some aren't. Usually reserved keywords like `SELECT`, `WHERE`, etc.. are case-insensitive.
It might be worth forcing to lower or uppercase for your WHERE clause.

Consider using `LOWER` or `UPPER` to force lower or upper case

`SELECT name from city where LCASE(countrycode) = "jpn"`

I haven't used it personally so it might be worth benchmarking for speed.

Comment: LCASE is platform dependent -- some use LOWER