# How can I make my query case-sensitive?

Tags: sql, vb.net, dataadapter

I want to make this query case sensitive.

```
                Managers.AddParameters("@Manager_Username", 
                TXTUsername.Text.ToString)
                Managers.AddParameters("@Manager_Password", 
                TXTPassword.Text.ToString)
                Managers.MakeQuery("SELECT Manager_Username, 
                Manager_Password, 
                Manager_ID, Manager_Name FROM SaleManager WHERE 
                Manager_Username = @Manager_Username 
                AND Manager_Password = @Manager_Password")
```

At the moment it doesn't matter if the data i enter is uppercase or lowercase.
I am using data adapters

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1831120/7531598

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do a case sensitive search in WHERE clause (I'm using SQL Server)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831105/how-to-do-a-case-sensitive-search-in-where-clause-im-using-sql-server)

Comment: ...or `case ensative` as the case may be.  Passwords should never be stored as plain text.

Comment: @HoneyBadger, oops, I misread. Force a case sensitive collation is my tip then!

Comment: @Plutonix What would be a better way to store my passwords store my passwords.

Comment: Create a [hash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10402129/251311) of the password and store that.

Comment: Note that hashing the password string should also make the passwords case sensitive.