# How to use StringComparer in custom Linq extension method?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

My project is having some user defined linq extension methods for orderby, ThenBy etc. And I want to sort a list of object based on a string property in that object by ignoring its case.

Code:

```
public static IOrderedQueryable<TEntity> OrderUsingSortExpression<TEntity>(this IQueryable<TEntity> source, string sortExpression) where TEntity : class
        {
            OrderedQueryable<TEntity> result = null;
            try
            {
                  result =  source.OrderBy("Title") 
                    // I'm getting an exception here in result.

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               result = source as IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>;
            }
            return result;
        }

    public static IOrderedQueryable<TEntity> OrderBy<TEntity>(this IQueryable<TEntity> source, string fieldName) where TEntity : class


     {
            MethodCallExpression resultExp = GenerateMethodCall<TEntity>(source, "OrderBy", fieldName);
            return source.Provider.CreateQuery<TEntity>(resultExp) as IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>;
        }
    private static MethodCallExpression GenerateMethodCall<TEntity>(IQueryable<TEntity> source, string methodName, String fieldName) where TEntity : class
            {
                Type type = typeof(TEntity);
                Type selectorResultType;
                var StrComp = StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase;
                LambdaExpression selector = GenerateSelector<TEntity>(fieldName, out selectorResultType);
                MethodCallExpression resultExp = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), methodName,
                                new Type[] { type, selectorResultType },
                                source.Expression, Expression.Quote(selector), Expression.Constant(StrComp));
                return resultExp;
            }
```

But at the end I'm receiving an exception:

> Static members = error CS0119: 'NotSupportedException' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

I think, it is expecting Enumerable source instead of Queryable. But I can't change source type. How can I resolve this?

Comment: `Linq to SQL` translate your `linq` queries to `sql` the  comparison type between strings depends entirely on your database coalition settings.

Comment: Both entity framework (full and core) and linq-to-sql don't support setting the collation (how strings are compared) through `StringComparer` and similar methods.

Comment: Note that on SQL Server normally columns are searched in a case insensitive way (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831105/how-to-do-a-case-sensitive-search-in-where-clause-im-using-sql-server)

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve] including a call that shows that error?

Comment: @nvoigt I have code in question, please check.

Comment: What does GenerateSelector do? Can you build a ConsoleApplication1 with that code to ensure it's actually a [mcve]?

Comment: It will give you a lambda expression ex. if your fieldname is **"Title"** , the lambda expression will be like, **entity => entity.Title**