# How can it happend a simple string condition ignore case-sensitive without any toLower method

Tags: c#, winforms

I just write a simple method to get user data from database by "UserName" and its work but it's not case-sensitive , without any "toLower()" methods or something like that...
and this is a big problem because it's think "Admin" equal to "admin" but this two actually not equal together ...
please some body tell me what should I do???

```
public List<UserViewModel> GetByName(string userName)
        {
            return db.UserTBL.Where(u => u.UserName == userName).
                Select(u => new UserViewModel
                {
                    UserName = u.UserName,
                    UserFullName = u.UserFullName,
                    UserPassword = u.UserPassword,
                    UserImage = u.UserImage
                }).ToList();
        }
```

Comment: Did you check if your database collation is case-sensitive?

Comment: Check out [database collation guide](https://database.guide/what-is-collation-in-databases/).

Comment: I have to ask, why would you want a `case-sensitive` database ? I would do all I possible can to avoid it

Comment: @Rafalon thanks for your attention friend I didn't know about it and now go to find out

Comment: @PeterWolf thanks bro I will...

Comment: @GuidoG that's not a question , my question is why it's happend

Comment: sql-server is `case-insensitive` by default. That is why it happened. I guess you want it to stay that way, except for the password. Having usernames case-sensitive seems a bit strange to me, but if that is what you really want than Patrick Hofman's answer can help you

Comment: @GuidoG you right friend , I don't know about it and I just find out right now , and i'm so thankful all of you guys for learn me something new

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831105/how-to-do-a-case-sensitive-search-in-where-clause-im-using-sql-server) is another option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably caused by your database being set up to match case-insensitive.

Check the collation settings of the database platform you are using. You can set it either globally, for the entire database, or for that column specifically.

Answer (score 0):

with guide guys give me here I do like picture below and it's work for me 
step 1 : choose the field in design mode 
step 2 : choose collation properties
step 3 : choose windows collation
step 4 : choose Dictionary sort
step 5 : choose Case Sensitive
and it's work for me
  [the five Steps I do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DncE.png)