# WHERE clause with '=' operator doesn't return exact match

Tags: sql, sql-server, exact-match, ssms-19

I tried a `SELECT` with a `WHERE` clause searching for a wrong string but the result showed the right string, which further testing showed the `WHERE` clause with the `=` operator doesn't return the exact match.

I have tried to search for solutions but can't find any through Google or Stack Overflow.

Simplified example

```
SELECT * 
FROM LoginCredential 
WHERE UserID = 'ad'
```

[The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAEEp.png)

Comment: Are you referring to the fact that the search is not case sensitive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You question appears to have already been asked and has an answer here [How to do a case sensitive search in WHERE clause (I'm using SQL Server)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831105/how-to-do-a-case-sensitive-search-in-where-clause-im-using-sql-server)

For your easy reference:

```sql
SELECT *
From LoginCredential
WHERE UserID = 'ad'  COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
```

Comment: In that case flag the question as a duplication rather than answering it again.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem. Although I had seen the linked answer before, I do not understand the terminology then, sorry for the duplicate question.

Answer (score -3):

If you are using MySQL, looks like you create a DB in case insensitive, like utf8mb4_general_ci, ci means case insensitive, change to utf8mb4_general_cs (case sensitive)

Comment: The SQL Server and SSMS tags that are on the question pretty much tells you that they're not using MySQL.