# Make Varchar PK case-sensitive?

Tags: sql-server

I have to store Ids of type Varchar in my SQL Server database table. The Ids are unique and they will be used for update/delete operations.

So I decided to make them PK. The problem is, that only one of the PKs "A" and "a" is allowed, while both may be in the dataset I have to import.

```
INSERT INTO test(test) VALUES('A')
INSERT INTO test(test) VALUES('a')
Violation of the PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_test'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.test'.
```

Can I make the PK case-sensitive - so that after "A" is inserted, "a" may be inserted but "A" may be not?

Comment: possible duplicate of [T-SQL: How do I create a unique key that is case sensitive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/485359/t-sql-how-do-i-create-a-unique-key-that-is-case-sensitive)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to change the collation of the database to one that is case ensitive, like `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS`.

You can do this in SQL Server Management Studio via the Object Explorer by right-clicking on the database and going to "Properties > Options" then the "Collation" drop-down.  Any one that has "CS" in the name is case-sensitive.

Of course, as was pointed out in the comments, this is probably overkill.  You can also override the collation for just one column, as described here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190920.aspx

Comment: *cough* you mean to a case *sensitive* collation - the user wants A and a to be two different, valid PKs

Comment: You mean "case sensitive".

Comment: @ObsidianPhoenix -- No, I don't.  "Case Insensitive" means you can do exactly what he wants because the collation refers to *comparing* values, meaning that `A` and `a` will be treated the same.  *cough*.

Comment: Changing the collation of the *whole database* is way overkill, as the collation on the PK column can be changed, as in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190920.aspx - if the whole database is case sensitive, it has knock-on effects, eg all variable names in stored procedures become case sensitive.

Comment: Exactly. And thats NOT what the OP wants.

Comment: @stuartd -- probably.  It's one option, though.

Comment: @ObsidianPhoenix -- Reading is apparently not my strong point :)  I've updated my answer

Comment: wow wow just collate the column to SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS that would do.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making the entire database case-sensitive, just make the primary-key-column case-sensitive:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.T_NodeNames
(
     node_name national character varying(20) COLLATE German_PhoneBook_100_CS_AS_KS_WS_SC_UTF8 NOT NULL
    ,tag_name national character varying(20) NULL
    ,tag national character varying(20) NULL
    ,node_type int NULL 
    ,deprecated int NULL
    ,descr national character varying(128) NULL
    ,creation_mechanism national character varying(50) NULL
    ,support national character varying(50) NULL
    ,use_instead national character varying(50) NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT pk_node_names PRIMARY KEY(node_name) 
); 
GO
```

or as table-variable:

```
DECLARE @nodeNames TABLE 
(
     node_name national character varying(20) COLLATE German_PhoneBook_100_CS_AS_KS_WS_SC_UTF8 NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
    ,tag_name national character varying(20) NULL 
    ,tag national character varying(20) NULL 
    ,node_type int NULL 
    ,deprecated int NULL 
    ,descr national character varying(128) NULL 
    ,creation_mechanism national character varying(50) NULL 
    ,support national character varying(50) NULL 
    ,use_instead national character varying(50) NULL 
);
```