# Case sensitive matching in IN clause in SQL

Tags: sql, select

I have 2 rows in my table like this

- name: Charlie id: 26
- name: Frank id: 28

I want a case sensitive comparison.

I wrote a query like this

```
select *  
from table1 
where name in ('charlie', 'Frank') COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS;
```

but it is not working. What should be the query?

Comment: You want case INSENSITIVE or SENSITIVE matching? Your collate is `CS`

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039211/what-does-collate-sql-latin1-general-cp1-ci-as-do

Comment: i want case sensitive matching.

Comment: What is the current collation of your table?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, i am new to sql, i dont know what collation is.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/485394/224370

Comment: @IanMercer that worked.

Comment: "but it is not working." That's not telling us anything. Also, SQL is too general. What rdbms are you working with? Please read the first couple of paragraphs in the [sql tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your column to case sensitive. Something like:

```
ALTER TABLE table1
ALTER COLUMN name VARCHAR(100) 
COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/485394/224370 which is a slightly different question, but same answer applies.